# How to prove that this space is complete

Tags: general-topology, complete-spaces

I have in $E=\mathcal{C}([a,b])$ (the set of continuous function) this set $M_k$ the set of the $k-$Lipschitzienne function that is $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq k |x-y|,~ \forall x,y\in [a,b]$$

I want to prove that $(M_k,d_{\infty})$ is a complete space.

Let $(f_n)$ a Cauchy sequence in $(M_k,d_{\infty})$ that is $$\lim_{p,q\in\infty}d_{\infty}(f_p,f_q)=\sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f_p(x)-f_q(x)|=0$$ then we can say that $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy in the complete metric space $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$ then it converge to $f(x)$

How to prove that $f$ is continuous?

**Edit: I don't know how to prove that $(E,d_{\infty})$ is complete.**

Thank you

Comment: What's $k$-Lipschitzienne? You mean $k$-Lipschitz i.e. $f$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq k d(x,y)$?

Comment: Note that if $f_n \to f$ , then since $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)| \le k |x-y|$ for all $x,y$ then this will be satisfied by the limit function since the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 3):

Since $C([a,b])$ is complete it suffices to show that $M_k$ is closed. So, let $f_n \in M_k$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly. We want to show that $f \in M_k$. This follows from a $3-\epsilon$ argument:

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \le |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) -f_n(y)| +|f_n(y) - f(y)|$$
$$\le 2\|f_n-f\|_\infty + k|x-y| \to k|x-y|.$$

Comment: Rightmost $f_n(x)$ on the first line should be $f(y)$, no?

Comment: Yes, fixed, thanks

Comment: @DavidBowman i don't have that $\mathcal{C}([a,b]), d_{\infty})$ is complete? how to do that ?

Comment: Use the Cauchy Criterion and that uniform limit of continuous is continuous

Comment: That is my problem how to prove that f is continuous, please edit your answer to complete my idea @DavidBowman

Comment: Try to adapt the idea in my proof

Comment: @DavidBowman sorry but i can't accept your answer, you dont answer my question

Comment: I think you need to put some effort in on your own

Comment: I DO THE EFFORT i begin the proof i asked about continuity tht's all